# How to change color of texblock inside gridview itemtemplate on hover in UWP app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, gridview, uwp

I've created a `gridview` as shown in the image below. In which each item consists of a `stackpanel` containing and image and a textblock. I want to change the background color of  `gridviewitem` and the `textblock` on hover of `gridviewitem` .

[image]

I've managed to change the background color of `gridview` item by using `PointerOverBackground` in `gridviewitempresenter` .
How can I change the color of textblock on hover ??

I've tried this code but I'm sure there will be a better way to achieve this

```
 private void StackPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)sender;

     foreach (var item in sp.Children)
     {
         if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(TextBlock)))
         {
             TextBlock tb = item as TextBlock;
             brush = new SolidColorBrush();
             brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
             tb.Foreground = brush;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change color of texblock inside gridview itemtemplate on hover in UWP app?

For your requirement, the better way is using
[`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to edit the property witin `DataTempate`. You could use `EventTriggerBehavior` to detect the pointer hover event then edit textblock's property. For the detail please refer the following code.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="GridPanel">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="InfoTextBlock" Text="{Binding}" />
        <TextBlock
                x:Name="FlagTextBlock"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="Hover"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                >
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=GridPanel}">
                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                            PropertyName="Visibility"
                            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=FlagTextBlock}"
                            Value="Visible"
                            />
                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                            PropertyName="Foreground"
                            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=InfoTextBlock}"
                            Value="Red"
                            />
                    </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>

                    <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=GridPanel}">
                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                            PropertyName="Visibility"
                            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=FlagTextBlock}"
                            Value="Collapsed"
                            />
                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                            PropertyName="Foreground"
                            TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=InfoTextBlock}"
                            Value="Black"
                            />
                    </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi just wanted to extend this question a bit. `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` are working fine but how can we manage the `PointerPressed` event. I wanted to change the text color when `PointerPressed` fires as well. But the problem is
`PointerExited` is still working which changes textcolor again. How to manage this case ?

Comment: @Mohit any update on this?